# Global variables vs. passing a value into a function?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm new to JavaScript, and have a simple (I presume) question regarding best practices for accessing variables in functions:

When should I declare a global variable, as opposed to simple passing a value into a function?

Comment: There are already many questions on StackOverflow with respect to the use of global variables in JavaScript. You'll find lots of information if you use the search field at the top right of this page.

Comment: @patrickdw : Sorry about that. Like I said, I'm new to JavaScript and sometimes have trouble finding things on my own. I just did another search here on StackOverflow to see what I could find -- not very much which is applicable (probably due to my JavaScript newbie state). I would love to read aforementioned material! What would be a good way to search for it?

Comment: This search ["when should I use global variables in javascript"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=when+should+I+use+global+variables+in+javascript) should give you plenty of material. You'll find that the consistent answer is to avoid globals if at all possible. Any variable not declared inside a function, or declared without using `var`, will be global.

Comment: @NathanArthur thank you for asking the question. When I google searched 'javascript better pass object to function or declare object global' I got your result and the answer I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring a global variable should only be used as an option of last resort.

Global variables are bad in general and especially so in javascript.  There is simply no way to prevent another piece of javascript from clobbering your global.  The clobbering will happen silently and lead to runtime errors.

Take the following as an example.

```
// Your code
myParam = { prop: 42 };
function operateOnMyParam() {
  console.log(myParam.prop);
}
```

Here i've declared 2 global variables

- myParam
- operateOnMyParam

This might work fine while testing your javascript in isolation.  However what happens if after testing a user combines your javascript library with my javascript library that happens to have the following definitions

```
// My code
function myParam() {
  console.log("...");
}
```

This also defines a global value named myParam which clashes with your myParam.  Which one wins depends on the order in which the scripts were imported.  But either way one of us is in trouble because one of our global objects is dead.

Comment: Could you explain, or link to someone else's explanation of, why this is?

Comment: The explanation here is pretty good, actually.  As an (overly simplistic, and badly designed) example: say you have some JS that does a client-side shopping cart, and store your cart in a global called 'items'.  Now say someone else comes along and writes a script that manipulates a single, ever-present collection of items.  And guess what they called their global variable.  Now, one of those scripts is going to trample all over the other's 'items', causing the other to break.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and links! (Accepted)

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many reasons.. but an easy one is.. The argument of a function only exists in the function, while it's running. A global variable exists all the time, which means:

- it takes up memory until you manually 'destroy' it
- Every global variable name needs to be unique
- If, within your function.. you call another function.. which ends up calling the first function, all of a sudden you may get unexpected results.

In short: because the function argument only lives for a really short time and does not exist outside the function, it's much easier to understand what's going on, and reduced the risk of bugs greatly.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with framework-less JavaScript I'll store my simple variables and functions in an object literal as to not clutter up the global namespace.

```
var myObject = {
   variableA : "Foo",
   variableB : "Bar",
   functionA : function(){
      //do something
      //access local variables
      this.variableA
   }
}

//call functions and variables
myObject.variableA;
myObject.functionA();
```